# Comparing Items in a List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have a library that contains documents. This library has an approval workflow attached to it. What my problem is that, everytime I make a new version of the document that I had I want the workflow status to change from APPROVED to SUPERSEDED whenever the new version is approved by the approvers and remains to be in APPROVED status if the new version is not approved yet...

Please help..

[Image of my Library..](http://dc424.4shared.com/img/PrBqqPVD/s7/0.43189366527900896/1_online.png?async&0.20142673631198704)

Additional information:

This document library has the same format for all added documents.. What would be the difference is its content. What I want to check is if the title is equal and both of them are approved. change the status of the document which was made first..

Comment: This looks like an InfoPath forms library, not a regular document library. Versioning in document libraries will not create new files. And in this case you are also not creating a new version of a file. You are adding a new file (or form).

Comment: yes yes.. this is an infopath form library.. sorry.. forgot to mention about that.. do you know any solution about this? :)

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this sufficiently. Are all forms in the library versions of each other? Does each subsequent form eventually override the previous form when it is approved? If so, you could create a workflow that checks the current item ID, then checks its status. If the status is "x", change another item in the list, i.e. the item with the ID of the current item minus one.

Comment: This document library has the same format for all added documents.. What would be the difference is its content. What I want to check is if the title is equal and both of them are approved. change the status of the document which was made first.. :))

Comment: Well, you can do that with a SharePoint Designer workflow. When a new file is posted, get the ID of the previous item, compare the titles, compare the status and make the changes. It seems to me that this is not the best way to deal with the technology. An InfoPath forms library usually gets populated by forms created with InfoPath. And with InfoPath, you have a wealth of tools to your avail to handle forms and their content and/or kick off a workflow.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for helping.. :) Ill try that. ^_^ hope i can do that.. :))